# How to set shipping rule in magento2?

Tags: magento2, shipping, rules

**How to set below rule?**

Shipping & Handling Fee is `20%` if the order is between `$50 to $150`, `15%` if the order is between `$150 to $300`.

Comment: please follow the below link https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-set-up-free-shipping-rules-in-magento-2/

Comment: Which shipping method you are planning to use?

Comment: This is why I love Magento. A question you seek which is 2 years old and nobody have an answer yet...